# Diablo 3 under Wine is safe?

Tags: wine, games

I heard a lot about Blizzard banning a lot people who used Wine to run Diablo 3 on Linux. After that I also heard that they actually were cheaters - and that's the only reason of ban.

Can someone tells me if playing D3 on Linux is safe? Game is quite expensive...

Thanks!

Comment: I saw the same thing, Blizzard claims it was cheating.

Comment: I was banned after playing on Linux for a week, then took a month break, then played 1 night back on Windows, and next day I was banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blizzard actually thought about supporting Linux and it may become true this summer:
http://steamforlinux.com/?q=en/node/162

I was playing Diablo 3 on a free account on Archlinux and they didn't ban me... Many people play World of Warcraft on Linux without any problems since those Blizzard games run better on Linux than on Windows. Is there any reason for banning someone for this actually? If they ever do this because of playing the game on Linux, they are stupid because it's not a reason.

But really after reading some stuff on the Internet: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5978861022
It looks risky...

If your PC is powerful enough you could create a virtual machine in VMware player/Virtualbox (VBox has bad 3D support)

Comment: That would awesome! I would feel much, much more comfortable. With official support (and without ban-because-we-can-but-we-don't-know-why). Thanks for info!

Answer (score 1):

I am a Diablo 3 player and so is my brother. We are playing on Ubuntu 13.04 64 Bit using the recommendations found in [WINEHQ DIABLO 3](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13484)

My brothers account was suspended but this lasted 2 days. After it was confirmed the problems with Wine, Blizzard fixed the account and many other accounts that were wrongly detected as cheaters. This is an old problem that is not affecting anyone I know that plays Diablo 3 right now.

Just follow the steps mentioned in: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25953

Or install [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) which provides all the requirements needed to have a proper installation for Diablo 3 (Assuming you have the hardware for it):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I manage to run it with help of PlayOnLinux - and it run pretty sweet. Thanks, I'm feeling betetr now - gonna get D3 pretty soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Other users have run Diablo 3 with Wine under Linux. However, running Diablo 3 is not supported by Blizzard, so they could at any moment block you or ban you.

So, no, there are no guarantees. Buy games meant for Linux instead.

Comment: Yeah, I would - but I never heard of good hack'n slash game for Linux. I've tried to run Torchlight 2 on Linux - but I have Steam version, and just can;t manage to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's bannable, they just don't offer any support.
On a sidenote, You better have one hell of a setup to run D3 under Wine.
And the game is quite a dissapointment :(

Comment: My PC is 2 years old - and it never was hardcore gaming machine ;) I had poor first impression with D3 - but after spending some time in demo (quite long and all classes) I've changed my mind :)